# unexpected end of file in bash_profile using gedit

Tags: bash

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
   source ~/.bashrc 
fi
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib:/usr/local/cuda/lib64
export ANDROID_API_LEVEL=android-14
export ANDROID_NDK=$HOME/android-ndk
```

I get the unexpected end of line after I inserted the if statement. However, when I used the dos2unix converter, it worked fine. I don't know why this is the case because I was editing using gedit or nano and still getting this problem.I am using a native Ubuntu 12.04 system. Any idea about the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check `~/.bashrc`; that could be the source of the error.